# system wide config variables do not work on Mac OS X

Tags: git, macos, bash

I am able to set variables at the local and global level, but not system wide.

These commands work:

```
git config --local core.editor "subl"
git config --global core.editor "subl"
```

but this does not ( even as sudo )

```
git config --system core.editor "subl"
```

It give error:

> error: could not lock config file
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/etc/gitconfig: No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/etc` first:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/etc
```

Comment: also the documentation states that it is in `/usr/etc` but your solution work, you just need to fix your typo use -> usr.

Comment: The only reference I can find says it looks for `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`, and presumably the Mac OS X installation uses `/Library/.../CommandLineTools/usr` for `$(prefix)`.

Comment: Check the online pdf here - https://progit2.s3.amazonaws.com/en/2016-01-16-e468b/progit-en.996.pdf - p39 and it clearly states `/usr/etc` , which book-page are you referring to ?

Comment: See the FILES section of `git help config`. (ProGit actually says `/etc/gitconfig`; I don't know if that's an error or an assumption made by Git at the time the book was written.)

Comment: Clearly an error as they did not qualify it as "usually here".  git help config is more accurate as it uses the `(prefix)` ... why does it have that dollar sign ( that makes me think of jQuery of running a bash subshell.

Comment: I think it's pseudo-code influenced by `make`'s parameter expansion syntax.